# ¿Cómo obtener el numero de líneas que contiene un archivo de texto?

Tags: c++

Necesito saber cuantas líneas tiene un fichero con la extensión .txt para después poder eliminar la primera línea ya que tiene encabezados que no me sirven.

Si me pueden ayudar lo agradecería mucho!!

Hasta ahora llevo esto, si bien me da el valor correcto de líneas que son 6, no sé si es la manera correcta de hacerlo y si me podría dar problemas.

```
int main(){
ifstream archivoEntrada;
ofstream archivoSalida;
int contLinea = 0;
string linea;
string texto;

archivoEntrada.open("Prueba.txt");
    if(archivoEntrada.fail()){
        cout << "Error al abrir el archivo." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
archivoSalida.open("salida.txt");

while(getline(archivoEntrada,linea)){
    texto = texto + linea+"\n";
    contLinea++;

}
archivoSalida << texto << endl;

archivoSalida.close();
archivoEntrada.close();
return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

No le veo problema a la función que tienes originalmente, también puedes intentar con con la sigiente función contando los \n

```cpp
  std::ifstream inFile("file"); 
  std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile), 
             std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n');
```

referencias: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072795/how-to-count-lines-of-a-file-in-chttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072795/how-to-count-lines-of-a-file-in-c

Answer (score -1):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es añadir el contador dentro del while, y sumarle uno, ya que cada vez que el while se ejecute, el contador sumará, y te dará como resultado el número de líneas que tiene el archivo.

```
int main(){
ifstream archivoEntrada;
ofstream archivoSalida;
int contLinea = 0;
string linea;
string texto;

archivoEntrada.open("prueba.txt");
    if(archivoEntrada.fail()){
        cout << "Error al abrir el archivo." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
archivoSalida.open("salida.txt");

while(getline(archivoEntrada,linea)){
    cout<<"L"<<contLinea<<"= "<<linea<<endl;
    contLinea++;
}
cout<< "El numero de lineas que tiene el archivo es de: " <<contLinea <<endl;
archivoSalida << texto << endl;

archivoSalida.close();
archivoEntrada.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Había pensado en algo similar, pero he investigado un poco y al parecer para contar como otra línea tiene que haber un salto de linea "\n" , por eso no sé si añadiendo un contador tan sencillo sea la opción correcta, por que no se si toma en cuenta los saltos de linea.

Comment: @IvanSuarez Una solución compleja no te asegura que la solución sencilla no sea la correcta. Con respecto a si es la solución adecuada recuerda que la función getline() obtiene CADA LÍNEA DEL ARCHIVO, y la guarda en la variable string linea; . La función getline() está adecuada para obtener específicamente una línea del archivo, cuando getline() encuentra un salto de línea ella finaliza su ejecución.